# Array include any value from another array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

What's the most efficient way to test if an array contains any element from a second array?

Two examples below, attempting to answer the question does `foods` contain any element from `cheeses`:

```rb
cheeses = %w(chedder stilton brie mozzarella feta haloumi reblochon)
foods = %w(pizza feta foods bread biscuits yoghurt bacon)

puts cheeses.collect{|c| foods.include?(c)}.include?(true)

puts (cheeses - foods).size < cheeses.size
```

Answer (score 313, accepted):

```
(cheeses & foods).empty?
```

As Marc-André Lafortune said in comments, `&` works in linear time while `any?` + `include?` will be quadratic. For larger sets of data, linear time will be faster. For small data sets, `any?` + `include?` may be faster as shown by Lee Jarvis' answer -- probably because `&` allocates a new Array while another solution does not and works as a simple nested loop to return a boolean.

Comment: When checking if an array contains an element from another array, wouldn't it make more sense to do (cheeses & foods).any? as this returns a true value if the arrays' do in fact contain any of the same elements?

Comment: @RyanFrancis, docs: `any?`: *The method returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil.* `empty?`: *Returns true if self contains no elements.*

Comment: @Nakilon I'm also confused why answer isn't `(cheeses & foods).any?` isn't the OP's question: if any foods are in cheeses? In his example, "feta" is in both, so result should be true, right? So why check `.empty?` on the intersection?

Comment: @SuckerForMayhem, because OP's question is "If any *are ...*?", not just "If any?". If "*are ...*" is omitted it's assumed to be "If any *is True?*" and would return False for array like `[false, false, false]`, while it obviously is not empty.

Comment: Is there any implementation in activerecord level?

Comment: Answering my own question: Food.where.overlap(name: ["chedder", "stilton", "brie", "mozzarella", "feta", "haloumi"])

Comment: What about when one of the arrays is empty? In my mind this should return false, but it does return true.

Comment: @leifg, the exact code in the answer is negative to exact title of the question. It returns true if there is nothing common between arrays and false if there is any match. If you add the `!` or `not(...)` around or change your `if` statement with `unless` or vice versa then you'll get false.

Answer (score 46):

How about [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003132)

```
>> cheeses = %w(chedder stilton brie mozzarella feta haloumi)
=> ["chedder", "stilton", "brie", "mozzarella", "feta", "haloumi"]
>> foods = %w(pizza feta foods bread biscuits yoghurt bacon)
=> ["pizza", "feta", "foods", "bread", "biscuits", "yoghurt", "bacon"]
>> foods.any? {|food| cheeses.include?(food) }
=> true
```

Benchmark script:

```
require "benchmark"
N = 1_000_000
puts "ruby version: #{RUBY_VERSION}"

CHEESES = %w(chedder stilton brie mozzarella feta haloumi).freeze
FOODS = %w(pizza feta foods bread biscuits yoghurt bacon).freeze

Benchmark.bm(15) do |b|
  b.report("&, empty?") { N.times { (FOODS & CHEESES).empty? } }
  b.report("any?, include?") { N.times { FOODS.any? {|food| CHEESES.include?(food) } } }
end
```

Result:

```
ruby version: 2.1.9
                      user     system      total        real
&, empty?         1.170000   0.000000   1.170000 (  1.172507)
any?, include?    0.660000   0.000000   0.660000 (  0.666015)
```

Comment: You can improve this by turning `cheeses` into a set.

Comment: Ran my own benchmark here  on ruby 2.2.7 and 2.3.4 and `any?, include?` was the fastest, set disjoint the slowest: https://gist.github.com/jaredmoody/d2a1e83de2f91fd6865920cd01a8b497

Comment: This benchmark is biased by the specific example mentioned and does not necessarily hold in a more general case. What if there were no common elements between the two arrays? What if the arrays were in a different order on each pass? What if feta appeared at the end of both arrays? As Marc-André stated, set intersection executes in linear time, so it makes sense that it is much more scalable for the general case, rather than the one specific example used purely to clarify the question.

Answer (score 27):

You can check if the intersection is empty.

```
cheeses = %w(chedder stilton brie mozzarella feta haloumi)
foods = %w(pizza feta foods bread biscuits yoghurt bacon)
foods & cheeses
=> ["feta"] 
(foods & cheeses).empty?
=> false
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use [`intersect?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-intersect-3F) since **ruby 3.1**

```
foods.intersect?(cheeses)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require "benchmark"
N = 1_000_000
puts "ruby version: #{RUBY_VERSION}"

CHEESES = %w(chedder stilton brie mozzarella feta haloumi).freeze
FOODS = %w(pizza feta foods bread biscuits yoghurt bacon).freeze

Benchmark.bm(15) do |b|
  b.report("&, empty?") { N.times { (FOODS & CHEESES).empty? } }  
  b.report("any?, include?") { N.times { FOODS.any? {|food| CHEESES.include?(food) } } }  
  b.report("disjoint?") { N.times { FOODS.to_set.disjoint? CHEESES.to_set }}
end  
                      user     system      total        real
&, empty?         0.751068   0.000571   0.751639 (  0.752745)
any?, include?    0.408251   0.000133   0.408384 (  0.408438)
disjoint?        11.616006   0.014806  11.630812 ( 11.637300)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set.new(cheeses).disjoint? Set.new(foods)
```

Comment: Also in my (unscientific) benchmark, set disjoint was significantly slower than other methods: https://gist.github.com/jaredmoody/d2a1e83de2f91fd6865920cd01a8b497

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm not sure why it wasn't Set.new but I just edited it. I tried your performance benchmarks in 2.4.1. Mine did better but still not best using disjointed sets containing more words. I put my version in a comment on your gist. I also think `disjoint?` is very elegant, especially compared to "any?, include?". The original question did ask about both elegant and efficient.

Comment: `.to_set` method can be useful here `cheeses.to_set.disjoint?(foods.to_set)`