# How do I see if one string contains a keyword in a keyword list?

Tags: ruby

I want to see if one string contains a keyword in a keyword list.

I have the following function:

```
def needfilter?(src)
    ["keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5"].each do |kw|
        return true if src.include?(kw)
    end
    false
end
```

Can this code block be simplified in to one line sentence?

I know it can be simplified to:

```
def needfilter?(src)
    !["keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5"].select{|c| src.include?(c)}.empty?
end
```

But this approach is not so efficient if the keyword array list is very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was  curious  what's the fastest solution and I created a benchmark of all answers up to now.

I modified [steenslag answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668832/676874) a bit. For tuning reasons I create the regexp only once not for each test.

```
require 'benchmark'
KEYWORDS = ["keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5"]
TESTSTRINGS = ['xx', 'xxx', "keyowrd_2"]

N = 10_000 #Number of Test loops

def needfilter_orig?(src)
    ["keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5"].each do |kw|
        return true if src.include?(kw)
    end
    false
end 
def needfilter_orig2?(src)
    !["keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5"].select{|c| src.include?(c)}.empty?
end
def needfilter_any?(src)
  ["keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5"].any? do |kw|
    src.include? kw
  end
end
def needfilter_regexp?(src)
  !!(src =~ Regexp.union(KEYWORDS))
end
def needfilter_regexp_init?(src)
  !!(src =~ $KEYWORDS_regexp)
end
def needfilter_split?(src)
  (src.split(/ /) & KEYWORDS).empty?
end

Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('orig') { N.times { TESTSTRINGS.each{|src| needfilter_orig?(src)} } }
  b.report('orig2') { N.times { TESTSTRINGS.each{|src| needfilter_orig2?(src) } } }
  b.report('any') { N.times { TESTSTRINGS.each{|src| needfilter_any?(src) } } }
  b.report('regexp') { N.times { TESTSTRINGS.each{|src| needfilter_regexp?(src) } } }
  b.report('regexp_init') { 
   $KEYWORDS_regexp = Regexp.union(KEYWORDS) # Initialize once
    N.times { TESTSTRINGS.each{|src| needfilter_regexp_init?(src) } }
  }
  b.report('split') { N.times { TESTSTRINGS.each{|src| needfilter_split?(src) } } }

} #Benchmark
```

Result:

```
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------------
orig          0.094000   0.000000   0.094000 (  0.093750)
orig2         0.093000   0.000000   0.093000 (  0.093750)
any           0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.109375)
regexp        0.578000   0.000000   0.578000 (  0.578125)
regexp_init   0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.046875)
split         0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.125000)
-------------------------------------- total: 1.047000sec

                  user     system      total        real
orig          0.078000   0.000000   0.078000 (  0.078125)
orig2         0.109000   0.000000   0.109000 (  0.109375)
any           0.078000   0.000000   0.078000 (  0.078125)
regexp        0.579000   0.000000   0.579000 (  0.578125)
regexp_init   0.046000   0.000000   0.046000 (  0.046875)
split         0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.125000)
```

The solution with regular expressions is the fastest, if you create the regexp only once.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a nice use case for [Enumerable#any?](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Enumerable#any?-instance_method) method:

```
def needfilter?(src)
  ["keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5"].any? do |kw|
    src.include? kw
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def need_filter?(src)
  !!(src =~ /keyowrd_1|keyowrd_2|keyowrd_3|keyowrd_4|keyowrd_5/)
end
```

The `=~` method returns a fixnum or nil. The double bang converts that to a boolean.

Comment: You can also build the regex with `/#{keywords.join('|')}/` (assuming keywords don't include symbols). This is probably the fastest solution. But try to benchmark all answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I'd do it:

```
def needfilter?(src)
    keywords = Regexp.union("keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5")
    !!(src =~ keywords)
end
```

This solution has:

- No iteration
- Single regexp using Regexp.union

Should be fast for even a large set of keywords. Note that hardcoding the keywords in the method is not ideal, but I'm assuming that was just for the sake of the example.

Comment: Thanks, your approach is very nice. In my real code the keywords are from some extra configuration, here I just want to known which solution is better.

Comment: That's what I thought. You can save even more time by computing the union'ed keywords exactly once and storing the resulting regexp outside the method, such as in an attribute. Then your entire method definition is simply `!!(src =~ @keywords)`.

Comment: Ruby's regex engine is fast too, so you don't take a hit when using big regex patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
def need_filter?(src)
  (src.split(/ /) & ["keyowrd_1","keyowrd_2","keyowrd_3","keyowrd_4","keyowrd_5"]).empty?
end
```

will work as you expect (as it's described in [Array include any value from another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3941945/1017941)) and will be faster than `any?` and `include?`.

Comment: src is a string, according to the question.

Comment: I've fixed it by splitting all string to words.

Comment: thanks, but this approach failed, the src string may be very complex. And I think it's not so efficient, because I only want to know the string hit any keyword, if so, ignore the other keywords and just return true